# Maven TestNG execution runs in ghost mode even after terminting the program

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, testng

I am using the Maven + TestNG combination to execute Selenium tests. In case I terminate the mvn run in-between, still the testng execution continues execution. I noticed that the testng execution is happening in a new java process. Once I killed the process from task manager, the ghost execution stops.

Please let me know, how to kill the testng process automatically in case termination of maven process from eclipse. This creates a bigger problem on running the suite from jenkins and cancelling the job in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...
We should use forkMode=never in pom.xml
(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-524)